# Ajax request in flask not working

Tags: python, ajax, flask

I am working on a flask app and I am sending this ajax request to '/repl' endpoint

```
     $.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url : "/repl?code=",
         data: "print \"hello\"",
         contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
         success: function(result){
             alert(result.output);
        }
      });
```

and code of my controller i.e. view.py is

```
   @app.route('/repl', methods=['GET'])
   @app.route('/repl/', methods=['GET'])
   def execute():
       code = request.args.get("code", None)
       print code
       # execute python code in sandbox
       out, err = exec_sandbox(str(code))
       return jsonify(success=1, output=out, error=err)
```

but it is not working. Code variable always receives None value. Please help

after running app, this request builds up

```
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Mar/2014 03:59:59] "GET /repl/?code=&print%20%22hello%22 HTTP/1.1" 200
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change ajax code to :

```
$.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url : "/repl",
     data: {url : "print \"hello\""},
     contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
     success: function(result){
         alert(result.output);
    }
  });
```

Comment: Yes It worked but I have passed the argument in data as {code: "print \"hell\o""}